# How to Validate MAC address Uploading to Database from Excel File? -

Tags: c#, asp.net

My application has a property where a User can upload data into database through Excel file upload.One of the Column in Excel file is "MAC ADDRESS" I do not want the user to Upload MAC ADDRESS in the format XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX INSTEAD XX-XX-XX-XX-XX-XX. If a user try to Upload with the format  XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX how to handle this situation? Once the user hit submit button(after uploading excel file), a pop up will appear populating all the data as it is in a grid-view, on that pop up there is a confirm button once the user hit confirm all the data are saved into the database but I do not want user to send MAC address in the format XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX, is there anyway to validate it?

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is, why not?  It would be simple to convert one form to the other for normalization before saving it to the database.

Having said that, the following regex could be used for validation:

```
[0-9a-z]{2}(-[0-9a-z]{2}){5}
```